# Relational Database Delete Concept in RavenDB

Tags: nosql, ravendb

I am new to Raven DB and new to the concept of No SQL DBs. I am trying to shed some of the concepts that come with RDBs. Once concept is that if a record is being used as a foreign key somewhere, an RDB won't let me delete the master record.

Suppose I wan't to delete a Category and that category's ID is being used in some Product then a RDB won't let me delete that record. This is quite helpful as I don't have to worry about accidently deleting the record. How can I apply the same concept to Raven DB? I want to use normalized structure like RDBs because I plan to use Raven DB in conjunction with some RDB. I want to be on the safe side just in case so that I don't end up in a situation where I have chaos due to experimenting with a new concept.

Hope I made sense,

Any help will be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such concept as a *foreign key constraint* in RavenDB.  Really, there is no *foreign key*.  All you have in your document is a string that can be used to go fetch another document.  We call that a relationship, but it is a loose term.  There is nothing going on under the hood to link those documents together and prevent you from doing that delete.

In the scenario you described, you would still be able to load the product.  But you would get a null if you tried to load the category using that product's category id.

You have to maintain these relationships yourself.  The only helper available is the [Cascade Delete Bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/bundles/cascade-delete) - but you still must wire up each entity for cascading.  It doesn't do it automatically like it would with a sql foreign key based cascade delete.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Matt,
Isn't there any way, maybe a bundle to apply this type of behaviour? Am I asking for something that is not applicable in document based DBs? The thing I want to understand is whether my concern which is valid in RDBMs world, still valid in No SQL world as well? If not what is the solution for storing common entities like Categories and Products in a No SQL DB?

Comment: You can store them exactly like you described. You just don't have the database working on your behalf to enforce the relationship constraint.  Yes, a bundle could be written to add this behavior, but it doesn't exist today.  Many would like it, but many would see it as a crutch, and it could have performance impacts. It would have to be applied sparingly.  I have experience writing Raven bundles. I'll give it some deeper thought.

Comment: With Raven you don't need to have a normalized structure just so you can use with a RDB. You'll be forfeiting much of the good from RavenDB by doing so. Try reading into SQL Replication and how this might help you.

Comment: I would take Matt Johnson's reply as an answer because he has elaborated how RavenDB is different from SQL Server and what lines should be taken. I would be glad to find out how people tackled similar situations with RavenDB.